# Setting variable equal to pattern match in a range

Tags: curl, awk

**My Objective**

I need to match two lines within a text range so that I can use one line to set a url to curl and the other match to set the output file name. If either of the patterns are not matched in the range, Then I want to just print an error and continue.

**Example input**

```
Non matching lines

<article>
Non matching lines
<h4 class="audio-module-title">A title</h4>
Non matching lines
<li class="audio-tool audio-tool-download"><a href="https://example.com/file.mp3"
</article>

Non matching lines
```

Ultimately, my goal is to iterate through all of the  text ranges and for each construct a curl command:

```
curl https://example.com/file.mp3 -o "A Title.mp3"
```

I think awk is the right choice but I'm having trouble working out how to do this. I have been able to find the range and filter all but the matching lines but I'm not sure how to handle the rest.

```
awk '/<article>"/,/<\/article/ {if (/<h4 class=/)print } {if (/<li class="audio-tool audio-tool-download">/)print }' inputfile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.sh
awk '
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
/<article>/   { f=1 }
/<\/article>/ { f=0 }
f {
    if ( sub(/.*<h4 class="audio-module-title">[[:space:]]*/,"") ) {
        sub(/[[:space:]]*<\/h4>.*/,"")
        if ( title != "" ) {
            printf "Error@%s[%d]: Got title %s but no URL.\n", FILENAME, titleFnr, title | "cat>&2"
        }
        title = $0
        titleFnr = FNR
    }
    else if ( sub(/.*<li class="audio-tool audio-tool-download">[^"]+"/,"") ) {
        sub(/".*/,"")
        url = $0
        if ( title != "" ) {
            print url, title
        }
        else {
            printf "Error@%s[%d]: Got URL %s but no title.\n", FILENAME, FNR, url | "cat>&2"
        }
        title = url = ""
    }
}
END {
    if ( title != "" ) {
        printf "Error@%s[%d]: Got title %s but no URL.\n", FILENAME, titleFnr, title | "cat>&2"
    }
}
' "$1" |
while IFS=$'\t' read -r url title; do
    echo curl "$url" -o "${title}.mp3"
done
```

.

```
$ ./tst.sh file
curl https://example.com/file.mp3 -o A title.mp3
```

Remove the `echo` when you're happy with the output after initial testing.

Comment: Awesome! This definitely solves the problem. Many, many thanks. When I finish modifying my existing script to make use of this I will post to share with others. 

Thank you again for pointing the way, Ed.

Comment: No, your solution works like a charm! Thank you again.